# How to convert data(tensor) across different deep learning frameworks directly in gpu without copying to cpu?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensor, mxnet

For example, I have a cuda tensor in pytorch, how to directly convert it to mxnet/tensorflow in gpu without copying it to cpu? Frequently copying data between cpu and gpu is very time-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to use [CUDA API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html) for that.

Sharing tensors via PyTorch is only supported on CPU.

And if you would try to do some Python exhibition you will be slow because of GIL.

Comment: I don't have it at the moment. @GuWang.